# scipy.sparse.load_npz attribute error

Tags: python, scipy

Trying to load a previously saved sparse matrix as described in the [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.load_npz.html):

```
import scipy

X_train = scipy.sparse.load_npz('training_data.npz')
```

works in a Jupyter notebook, but throws an attribute error when run from a  script on the same machine (macOS Sierra, Python version 2.7.12, SciPy version 0.19.0):

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'load_npz'
```

Also tried

```
import scipy.sparse

X_train = scipy.sparse.load_npz('training_data.npz')
```

and

```
from scipy import sparse

X_train = sparse.load_npz('training_data.npz')
```

to no avail. What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you mind trying to run `import scipy; scipy.__version__` from your computer and *not* the Jupyter notebook... I believe at one point I had two different versions installed. This may or may not be the problem. Just a guess.

Comment: @Dair I get 0.17.1 - how is that possible? When I do `pip freeze | grep scipy` I get `scipy==0.19.0`. And how do I make sure Python uses the latest installed version? I did `pip install scipy --upgrade` to get the latest version - was that the wrong thing to do?

Comment: Haha, idk. I just had the problem at one point and suspected you might have had it too. Were you able to upgrade it successfully though?

Comment: Looks like that's a new '0.19.0' function.  It's not in '0.18'

Comment: The functions are found in https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/sparse/_matrix_io.py.  It's a straight forward savez/load of a dictionary of the essential attributes of the sparse matrix.

Comment: @Dair, I finally made it work by wiping all versions of scipy and then reinstalling just the latest version. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your `scipy` is the correct version `0.19.0`. I have had issues in the past with syncing my vanilla python version with the Jupyter notebook before. Seems like this also happened here.